# CMake Error, following variables set to NOTFOUND

Tags: shell, cmake, kaldi

So im trying to install kaldi-GOP, when i run build.sh this error pops up

```
[root@localhost kaldi-gop]# ./build.sh
utils/check_dependencies.sh: all OK.
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
LIBCBLAS
    linked by target "gop" in directory /var/www/html/kaldi-gop/src
LIBLAPACK
    linked by target "gop" in directory /var/www/html/kaldi-gop/src

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/var/www/html/kaldi-gop/src/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/var/www/html/kaldi-gop/src/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

I've already installed and updated atlas, openblas and cmake libraries. Or at least i think i did. What can i do to help fix this and install kaldi-gop successfully?

Comment: Variable `LIBLAPACK` relates to `lapack` library. Variable `LIBCBLAS` probably relates to `cblas`, but I don't know whether it is compatible with openblas which you have.

Comment: what could i do to fix this? should i remove openblas?

Comment: In [src/CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/jimbozhang/kaldi-gop/blob/master/src/CMakeLists.txt) I have found following lines: `find_library (LIBCBLAS libcblas.so.3)`, `find_library (LIBLAPACK liblapack_atlas.so.3)`. They are about setting the variables with the libraries. Next two lines use these variables. I agree that hardcoding libraries so-versions (`libcblas.so.3`, `liblapack_atlas.so.3`) is not so good. If you are sure that your have libraries compatible to ones which are searched, you may edit given file with your libraries' names. (No need to change *variables*' names.)